# Deriving the (un)familiar arc-cosine integral identity

Tags: integration, trigonometry

In his [Theoretical Physics](https://books.google.com/books?id=btrCAgAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&pg=PA91#v=onepage&q&f=false), Joos condescends the following expression as "the familiar arc-cosine form":

$-\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{a+2 bx-hx^2}} \, dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt{h}}\arccos \left[\frac{b-hx}{\sqrt{a+b^2h}}\right]$

The only reason it is now "familiar" to me is that I have been staring at it for weeks, wondering how to derive it.  I can prove it to be valid by substituting the terms into the form I do know how to derive.

$d\arccos (u)=-\frac{du}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}$

But that doesn't tell me how it was originally derived.  I strongly suspect there is some geometric development which would illuminate the meaning of the variables and terms in the form Joos provides.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Start by completing the square in the integrand, then make a substitution to simplify.

Comment: Thanks.  That gave me AN answer.  I contacted my professor of introductory physics (which I never completed) some 33 years ago, and asked him about his geometric approach to a similar problem.  He doesn't deny having presented it, but claims to not remember how he did it.  He said he will get back with me on this.  If I gain any insight, I will share it.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\begin{align}
-\int\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{a+2bx-hx^2}}
&=-\frac1{\sqrt{h}}\int\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{\frac{ah+b^2}{h^2}-\left(x-\frac bh\right)^2}}\tag{1}\\
&=-\frac1{\sqrt{h}}\int\frac{\mathrm{d}\frac{hx-b}{\sqrt{ah+b^2}}}{\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{hx-b}{\sqrt{ah+b^2}}\right)^2}}\tag{2}\\
&=\frac1{\sqrt{h}}\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{hx-b}{\sqrt{ah+b^2}}\right)+C\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: complete the square and bring the $\frac1{\sqrt{h}}$ out front
$(2)$: move factors around to make it look like $\int\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}$
$(3)$: standard integral

Comment: Yes, thank you.  I had followed the previous advice and arrived at a much more long-winded version of the same.  It's not the answer I was looking for, but is far more satisfying than not having an answer.

Comment: I am not sure what answer you were looking for. If you supply some more information, perhaps someone can help.

Comment: I'm not as confident of this as I was when I first asked my question; but, I believe the variables in Joos's "familiar form" can be related to a geometric diagram which includes an ellipse.  Or perhaps a circle.  Something along these lines: http://math.caltech.edu/~nets/lecture19.pdf only with pictures.  Perhaps with some kind of coordinate transformation.